# How to add spacer in GTK+3?

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

I am using C GTK+3, using Glade for the GUI design. I have a GtkGrid with 1 row and 3 columns. I have a button on column 2 and I want to add a spacer in column 1 and 3 so the button stays in the middle of the window. 
Which GTK3 widget should I use to act as a simple 'spacer'?

Comment: I have a similar question, but without glade

Comment: Simply use the `halign` and `valign` properties on GtkWidget or use set_center_child on a GtkBox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your description I'm assuming your interface looks like so:

[image: Current]

I think your trying to achieve an interface like so:

[image: Belive]

Which can be achieved by changing the alignment from fill to centre in the 'Common' tab:

[image: How]

However if you wanted the button to be centred regardless of any content placed in Col 1 / 3 you would be better off with a GtkBox with a center widget:

[image: Might be]

Which is achieved like so:

Add a horizontally orientated GtkBox and enable center child

[image: Centre]

Add your button to the extra placeholder displayed

Set any content you want to the right of the button as pack end

[image: Pack End]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! That solved the problem.